# Синхронизация потоков между разными JVM

Tags: java, многопоточность, j2ee

Есть сервер приложений (WildFly), в нём делается синхронизация по номеру транзакции, т.е. чтобы одна транзакция не обрабатывалась одновременно в двух потоках.

Есть необходимость сделать кластер со вторым сервером, соответственно встаёт вопрос - как сделать синхронизацию между серверами? Т.е. например пришло одновременно несколько запросов в разные сервера по одной транзакции.

Какие есть наиболее популярные готовые решения? Можно своё решение сделать, но не хочется изобретать велосипед.
БД/лок файла/Terracota не предлагать.

Comment: остается клиент-серверную часть сделать.
Сервер сам будет на клиенты отправлять ID и говорить что нужно делать. а клиент обратно серверу результат

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян сервер просто так ничего не делает, какой ID он отправит? Да и клиент это не наш сервер, т.е. протокол или схему взаимодействия не поменять.

Comment: Ну что значит не предлагать, если вы сами запрашиваете распределенную блокировку?

Comment: @Etki БД/файлы медленно, Terracota - денег стоит и выглядит не самым простым решением. Что-то простенькое я могу за 1-2 дня накидать, например EJB сервис на каждом сервере со списком залоченных ID и парой методов tryLock, release которые при работе опрашивают удаленный сервис. Неужели нет чего-то подобного уже реализованного?

Comment: Огромный выбор популярных готовых решений: Hazelcast, Redis, GridGain (Apache Ignite), Zookeeper, Apache Helix. Практически любое in-memory хранилище.

Comment: Возможно вам понравится Helix - фреймворк специально создан для построения распределенных приложений. Но он использует Zookeeper, а тому нужно три ноды для работы. Redis легко заведется из коробки.

Comment: @Nofate спасибо

Comment: @Russtam с чего это БД медленно?

Comment: @Nofate Redis - очень плохой выбор, он крайне ненадежен, его не стоит использовать для чего-то более серьезного, чем деревянный кэш. Zookeper / Hazelcast гораздо лучше.